# JSON to CSV with UTF8 encoding in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with analysis of feelings and after having got twitter data with twython and saving them in a txt file in json format, I need to write them in CSV format. I can do this but special characters are not written, for example "Inclusão" is written "Inclus \ xc3 \ xa3o"
here is the code:

```
import json
from csv import writer

with open('data.txt') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

tweets = data['statuses']

#variables
times = [tweet['created_at'] for tweet in tweets]
users = [tweet['user']['name'] for tweet in tweets]
texts = [tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets]

#output file
out = open('tweets_file.csv', 'w')
print(out, 'created,user,text')
rows = zip(times,users,texts)
csv = writer(out)
for row in rows:
    values = [value.encode('utf8') for value in row]
    csv.writerow(values)
out.close()
```

Comment: `out = open('tweets_file.csv', 'w', encoding='latin-1')`

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i already solved the problem guys, thank you! the problem is that my text has already been encoded and i was trying to do this again.